# Problem in setting LSTM model for generation forecasting

Tags: lstm

I am new to Machine Learning. I tried to develop an LSTM model to forecast the data. The model structure is given below.

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 50)             11400     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 50)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 50)             20200     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 50)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_5 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 50)             20200     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 50)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 50)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1, 2)              102       
=================================================================
Total params: 51,902
Trainable params: 51,902
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The part of Data I used for training is below (second to six columns are inputs while seventh and eighth column is output):
[Training Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BADby.png)

However the loss is not decreasing and prediction of the system is average value rather than following the pattern of the system. Both images are attached. I don't know how to further improve it.
[Loss Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOz5K.png)
[Blue is original and orange is predicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auv6s.png)

Kindly guide me what/how I can improve it further. Any reference material will be helpful!

Comment: Please, provide further details so that the community can try to help you. Where did those data come from? Did you preprocess them? Did you check whether they could be the correct predictor for the problem you are trying to solve? Data without semantic are just numbers. They can be surprisingly meaningful for your problem, but it might be that they won't. Since you are new to Machine Learning, it's important that you know that **Machine Learning cannot be used as a black box.** You cannot expect to feed your data to a ML model and magically get the desired result...

Comment: Where did those data come from?
It's from NREL.
Did you preprocess them?
Yes @FrancescoAlongi, I took mean of every column individually using ```meanv = np.mean(var, axis = 0)```.
Did you check whether they could be the correct predictor for the problem you are trying to solve?
Yes, as per my knowledge, LSTM and Arima are two options. However I had to use LSTM as per test. Apart from that I tried multiple cost and loss functions however the result was same.

Comment: Yes, I know that Data without semantic are just numbers. They can be surprisingly meaningful for your problem, but it might be that they won't.

However I tried my best with available resources to learn it, however the best I could achieve is this. That's why I asked here if someone can guide me some direction, I would definitely look into it.